# How to quickly map data from ResultSet to some bean?

Tags: java, jdbc, mapping, resultset

I'm using jdbcTemplate, and have a ResultSet consisting of about 100 named fields. And I have some object (bean), consisting of all those fields and appropriate getters/setters.
Is there any way to just quickly map the result set to my object, so I don't need to manually call all those setters? Of course, assuming, that ResultSet returns fields with proper alias for every field?

Comment: Might be possible with a combination of ResultSetDynaClass and BeanUtils.copyProperties from apache commons, http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/, but that's just a guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering to myself - BeanPropertyRowMapper is what I need, many thanks to google

Comment: You should have mentioned that you are using the Spring framework.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping from database tables / columns to Java objects is called [object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

The standard Java API for this is the [Java Persistence API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) (JPA). There are several implementations of this API; one of the most well-known is [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/).

Note that JPA works on a higher level than JDBC. It's not simply a tool for converting a JDBC `ResultSet` to Java objects; it's a complete framework for mapping Java objects to and from records in a relational database.

There are also non-JPA based solutions such as [mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/) (formerly iBATIS).

Comment: thank you very-very much, but my question wasn't about non-JDBC solutions